# python remove part of lines

Tags: python, regex, split

i have a text file with some strings like:

```
test2@gmail.com:123456
test2@hotmail.com:124554134
test1@yahoo.com:fdsfsdfe
test5@gmail.com:9875464
```

now i want remove all strings before .com by python.

my code(but wrong):

```
import re

myline = open("file.txt" ,"r").readlines()

for single_line in myline:
    spline= single_line.rstrip()
    result = re.sub("\.com$", "", spline)
    print (result)
```

how can i do?
thanks

Comment: Do you want to get `123456`, `124554134`, `fdsfsdfe`, `9875464`? Is the criterion *get all after the first occurrence of `.com`*? Or maybe splitting with `:` is enough. Please clarify.

Comment: `myline` already contains contents of this file. There is no need to iterate. Regex can catch all matches.use `re.findall` or `re.finditer` and you'll get array with all matches.

Comment: ...but change .readlines to read()

Answer (score 3):

Why do you use `re`? Simply split the strings.

```
with open("file.txt" ,"r") as f:
    for single_line in f:
        print single_line.split(':')[1]
```

Comment: The use of `re` can be explained if `fdsfsdfe` can contain `:`.

Comment: Still, I will  use the `maxsplit` parameter then. `re` is clearly not needed here.

Comment: I saw your answer before I noticed OP posted an own answer. I posted [my solution with `rsplit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44494841/3832970) below.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493495/3832970) using `.*\.com` regex, you want to remove all the line contents up to the last occurrence of `com:`. You can do it with a [`str.rsplit`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rsplit.html):

> Returns a list of the words in the string, separated by the delimiter string (starting from right).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/x88uOr):

```
ss = ['test2@gmail.com:123456',
'test2@hotmail.com:124554134',
'test1@yahoo.com:fdsfsdfe',
'test5@gmail.com:9875464',
'no com']
res = [s.rsplit("com:")[1]  if "com:" in s else s for s in ss]
print(res)
# => ['123456', '124554134', 'fdsfsdfe', '9875464', 'no com']
```

So, either you get the part after the last `com:` or the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

i find the answer.
i use this:

```
import re

myline = open("file.txt" ,"r").readlines()

for single_line in myline:
    spline= single_line.rstrip()
    result = re.sub(".*.com:", "", spline)
    print (result)
```

Comment: This means you want to remove all the line contents up to the last occurrence of `com:`. Why not add the details to the question and you would get an answer, and possibly not just a solution, but also explanation of why it works?

Comment: See my answer below that shows how to achieve the same without a regex using `str.rsplit`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select only the `:124554134` or `:fdsfsdfe`

You could use this shown in the example: https://regex101.com/r/i2iA7T/1/

```
:[\d\w]+
```

Or if you want the line without the `:` just use a reverse lookup:

`(?<=:)[\d\w]+`

https://regex101.com/r/i2iA7T/2